# truth table for followings

Tags: logic, boolean-algebra

Hi I am new to this site.

I got an assessment to complete tomorrow. Its about Computer programming, and i am having trouble with these questions. Can anyone please help me.

Using truth tables show that:

1. $A+B+C = (A+B)+C$
2. $A\cdot 1 = A$
3. $A'\cdot B = (A+B)'$

please someone who knows the answer please help me.

Comment: What problems are you having?

Answer (score 1):

To make a truth table, you make columns for all the variables and rows for all combinations of truth values of the variables.  Then you make as many columns as you want to assess the truth value of the statement in question.  If you want to prove equality of two expressions, they must agree on all values of the truth value of the variables.  It looks like you may have miscopied two of the problems:  I would expect the first to be $A+(B+C)=(A+B)+C$ (because $+$ is usually defined as a binary operator) and the third is not correct.  I'll give some lines of the first:

$$\begin {array}{c|c|c|c|c|c} \\ A&B&C&(A+B)&(A+B)+C&A+B+C \\ \hline 
T&T&T&T&T&T\\T&T&F&T&T&T\\F&F&T&F&T&T \end {array}$$

There are five more lines.  Mine would usually be the first, second, and seventh lines in the table.

Comment: thanks for that. but our teacher had given us that way i mentioned earlier. i can add the things up but i cant get the last answer. i don't know how. how to show that its equal?

Comment: @Charuka:  what last answer do you mean?  can you do the other five rows of the first table?

Comment: ok this is the question which is given to me as the assessment
Using truth tables show that:

    A+B+C=(A+B)+C
    A⋅1=A
    A′⋅B=(A+B)′

the second one is hard i dont know how to make even the first step. but the first one i know how to do that A B C and (A+B) but we have to prove it right? the last answer should be (A+B)+C i dont know how to do that column. could you help me with those 3 questions. i am stuck

Comment: @Charuka:  To get $(A+B)+C$ you add the truth value you have in the $(A+B)$ column to the one in the $C$ column.  The second one just has two lines because there is only one variable.  $1$ is always True.  As I said before, the third is not correct, so your verification should fail.

Comment: @Charuka:  you might look at [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truth_table).  Their $\wedge$ is your $\cdot$ and their $\vee$ is your $+$

Comment: thanks allot!. how to show A.1=A using a truth table? that's the one which i cant even do one step

Comment: @Charuka:  Have you made any progress on 3 then?  It also involves and.  $A\cdot 1$ is $A$ and True.  what does that evaluate to if $A$ is True?  What if $A$ is False?

Comment: i did the last one as A'. B i first made A B and then i made A' i calculated the answer for that. and as the final i did (A+B)' took both A and B answer out and made it negative. i don't know how to show that second one. that A.1 confuses me. how to put it in the truth table

Comment: @Charuka:  The column under $A \cdot 1$ has the same truth value as $A$.  For the third, you should find disagreement when $A$ is False.

Comment: oh so the second will be something like this
A  A   A
0  0   0
0  1   0
1  0   0
1  1   1

sorry i cant type it like a truth table
 but will the last answer be everything 0 and the last number is 1

Comment: @Charuka:  it will have two columns, $A$ and $A\cdot 1$  It will have two rows, $T\ T$ and $F \ F$  Then you note that the two elements in each row are the same, which proves what you are after.